# How to Complete this Proof about wffs in Propositional Logic?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction, propositional-calculus

For any wff $\mathfrak{F}$, define $\mathfrak{F}^*$ as the wff derived from $\mathfrak{F}$ by replacing all $\wedge$ with $\vee$ and all $\vee$ with $\wedge$.

**Claim**: If all of the connectives of wff  $\mathfrak{C}$ come from $\{\wedge,\vee,\neg\}$, then $\mathfrak{C}$ is a tautology if and only if $\lnot\mathfrak{C}^*$ is a tautology.

**My Attempt at Proof**:

Let $\Diamond$ denote $\vee$ or $\wedge$. I induct on the number $n$ of $\Diamond$s in $\mathfrak{C}$.

If $n$ is zero, then each of $\mathfrak{C}$ and $\neg\mathfrak{C}^*$ is an atom or the negation of an atom and cannot be tautology. Therefore the claim is vacuously true.

For some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, suppose the claim holds for all wffs whose only connectives come from $\{\vee,\wedge,\neg\}$ and whose number of connectives of type $\Diamond$ is contained in the set $S=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Let $\mathfrak{C}$ have $n$ connectives of type $\Diamond$ and let all of its connectives come from $\{\vee,\wedge,\neg\}$. Then after reduction/elimination of repeated $\neg$ operators, $\mathfrak{C}$ must take one of the following two forms:

- $\mathfrak{D}\Diamond\mathfrak{E}$
- $\neg(\mathfrak{D}\Diamond\mathfrak{E})$

where $\mathfrak{D}$ and $\mathfrak{E}$ are wffs whose only connectives come from $\{\vee,\wedge,\neg\}$, having $k$ and $k'$ connectives of type $\Diamond$, respectively.

If $\mathfrak{C}$ has form $\mathfrak{D}\Diamond\mathfrak{E}$, then $\mathfrak{C}^*$ has form $\mathfrak{D}^*\Diamond ^*\mathfrak{E}^*$ and $\neg\mathfrak{C}^*$ has form $\neg(\mathfrak{D}^*\Diamond ^*\mathfrak{E}^*)$, which is logically equivalent to $\neg\mathfrak{D}^*\Diamond \neg\mathfrak{E}^*$ by De Morgan's law.

---

This is where I get stuck. I don't see how assuming that $\mathfrak{D}\Diamond\mathfrak{E}$ is a tautology helps to show that $\neg\mathfrak{D}^*\Diamond \neg\mathfrak{E}^*$ is a tautology, or vice versa. Maybe my approach to the proof won't be fruitful, but it feels close.

Comment: I think that you can't just treat $\wedge, \vee$ together like this. Do them separately, it's quite straightforward. [Nor do I believe that you can eliminate repeated $\neg$'s. $\neg\neg\neg\neg\alpha$ is a wff, and it is a different wff from $\alpha$.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof swapping logical connectors transforms tautology to contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490178/proof-swapping-logical-connectors-transforms-tautology-to-contradiction)

Comment: @MarkSaving I don't know, because "structural induction" appears nowhere in my textbook (Mendelson) and I wouldn't know where to go to learn about it properly. Many of the results in the book require mathematical induction, which I am familiar and comfortable with.

Comment: @ancientmathematician In the $\lor$ case, I start by assuming that $\mathfrak{C}$ is a tautology thus $\mathfrak{D}\lor\mathfrak{E}$ is a tautology. Thus, for every truth assignment to the statement letters of $\mathfrak{D}$ and $\mathfrak{E}$, either $\mathfrak{D}$ is true or $\mathfrak{E}$ is true. (I am stuck here.)

Comment: @Gary If you prefer to avoid structural induction, you can use strong induction on the total number of occurrences of $\neg$, $\land$, and $\lor$. But the general approach is exactly the same.

Comment: @MarkSaving Isn't that what I tried to do?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but you're probably stuck because $\mathfrak{D}\Diamond\mathfrak{E}$ can be a tautology without the sub-formulas being tautologies. Try a more general approach: Prove that $\varphi(\mathfrak{C}) = \varphi(\neg\mathfrak{C}^*)$ for any truth assignment $\varphi$.

Comment: @Gary You should read my answer to the linked duplicate. It explains how to solve the problem and why your approach won’t work.

Comment: @Sam I thought a "truth assignment" is a function from the set of atoms/statement letters/propositions to the set $\{0,1\}$, so that $\phi(\mathfrak{C})$ isn't well-defined.

Comment: @Gary Once a truth assignment is defined on the atoms it can be uniquely extended to all formulas via truth tables, and the extension is usually called by the same name. But if you prefer to keep the distinction, just change "$\varphi(\mathfrak{C}) = \varphi(\neg\mathfrak{C}^*)$" to 
"the truth value of $\mathfrak{C}$ determined by $\varphi$ equals the truth value of $\neg\mathfrak{C}^*$ determined by $\varphi$"

Comment: @Sam Thanks. I'll give this a try soon. Related: do you have any recommended text for intro. math logic that defines everything rigorously and proves results including the fact about truth assignments you noted? I prefer to define and prove everything but Mendelson is a bit too loose in Chapter 1.

Comment: @Gary Try **A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic**, it's available as a free download from the author at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339882222_A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic. The first chapter has a good section on  induction on formulas.

Comment: @MarkSaving I have not forgotten your comment. Thank you for your assistance. I plan to return to this later after I have tightened some things up.